# Vulkan: update Camera between dynamic viewports

Tags: vulkan

I am following the Vulkan tutorial series and I am using this base code(https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/21_descriptor_layout.cpp) and creating multiple dynamic viewports within the draw call like so. The modified code is within the backslashes.  I have setup the pipeline to enable viewport Dynamic states also.

```
void drawFrame() {


    vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, (std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max)());

    uint32_t imageIndex;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, (std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max)(), imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame] };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame] };
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    vkResetFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

    //////////////BEGINNING OF SETTING VIEWPORTS//////////////////////////////////////////

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;

    if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[imageIndex], &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
    }

    VkClearColorValue defaultClearColor = { { 1.025f, 0.025f, 0.025f, 1.0f } };
    VkClearValue clearValues[2];
    clearValues[0].color = defaultClearColor;
    clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = {};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    renderPassInfo.framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[imageIndex];
    renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
    renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = swapChainExtent;
    renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues;
    renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[imageIndex], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);


    VkCommandBuffer command_buffer = commandBuffers[imageIndex];
    for (int i = 0; i < DisplayManager::win.size(); i++) {

            uint32_t first_viewport = 0;
            std::vector<VkViewport> viewports;
            VkViewport viewport = {};

            //also have to flip models y.
            viewport.width = (float)DisplayManager::win.at(i).viewWidth * (((float)DisplayManager::screenWidth/(float)DisplayManager::initialX));
            viewport.height = -(float)DisplayManager::win.at(i).viewHeight* (((float)DisplayManager::screenHeight / (float)DisplayManager::initialY));

            viewport.x = DisplayManager::win.at(i).viewPortPosX * (((float)DisplayManager::screenWidth / (float)DisplayManager::initialX)); 
            viewport.y = (DisplayManager::screenHeight - DisplayManager::win.at(i).viewPortPosY* (((float)DisplayManager::screenHeight / (float)DisplayManager::initialY)));

            viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
            viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;


            viewports.push_back(viewport);
            vkCmdSetViewport(command_buffer, first_viewport, static_cast<uint32_t>(viewports.size()), viewports.data());

            VkRect2D scissor = {};
            scissor.offset = { 0, 0 };
            scissor.extent = swapChainExtent;
            vkCmdSetScissor(command_buffer, 0, 1, &scissor);

            vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[imageIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);
            vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[imageIndex], 3, 1, 0, 0);

    }
    vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[imageIndex]);

    if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[imageIndex]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain };
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

    result = vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || framebufferResized) {
        framebufferResized = false;
        recreateSwapChain();
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    }
    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
}
```

I can dynamically adjust and set the viewports, however what I'd like to do is update the camera transformation sent to the shader so each viewport can adjust it's camera viewmatrix independently with something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < DisplayManager::win.size(); i++) {
 //setViewport
 //update_camera_transform().
 //I've tried updating a single uniform butter object here and a dynamic uniform buffer object from
 //Sasha William's examples code. 
        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[imageIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);
        vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[imageIndex], 3, 1, 0, 0); 
}
```

I'm wondering if this is possible with the current setup provided by the base code or if it Isn't if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Being new to Vulkan, I think the question to this post would probably be more accurately described as "How to send different matrices/data to the shader within the draw call". 
One solution is to use Dynamic Uniform Buffers, as the number of camera viewports will also be dynamic for my use. 
Sacha Williams has an example on how to use Dynamic UBOS here. https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/dynamicuniformbuffer

I expanded on this base code to include 2 dynamic UBO's within one descriptor set, and to have another Dynamic UBO in another set (this allows me to update uniforms at a different rate independent of each set) and a push constant.  The Code below is based on Sacha William's Dynamic UBO example and is proof of concept, it is at best considered chicken scratch but provides the necessary setup for:

2 Dynamic UBOs in the same descriptor set.
1 Dynamic UBO in another descriptor set.
1 push constant.

Variables modified, setup all dynamic ubo buffers/alignments just like the original mat4 used in his example.  Update Dynamic Uniforms outside Draw call also like his example.

```
#define OBJECT_INSTANCES 125
#define CAM_INSTANCES 2

struct {
    vks::Buffer viewBuffer;
    vks::Buffer dynamicBuffer; 
    vks::Buffer Buffer_second;
    vks::Buffer dynamicBuffer_second;
} uniformBuffers;

struct {
    glm::mat4 projection_mat;
    glm::mat4 view_mat;
    glm::mat4 model_mat;
} uboVS;

struct { 
    glm::mat4 model_mat_secondary;
} uboVS_secondary; 

struct UboDataDynamic {
    glm::mat4 *model = nullptr;
} uboDataDynamic;
struct UboDataDynamic_second {
    glm::mat4 *model = nullptr;
} uboDataDynamic_second;

size_t dynamicAlignment;
size_t dynamicAlignment_second;

glm::mat4 pushConstants;



void setupDescriptorSetLayout()
    {
        /////////////////////////////set 0 layout///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        {
            std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding> setLayoutBindings =
            {
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutBinding(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0),
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutBinding(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 1),
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutBinding(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 2),
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutBinding(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 3),

            };

            VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorLayout =
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo(
                    setLayoutBindings.data(),
                    static_cast<uint32_t>(setLayoutBindings.size()));

            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &descriptorLayout, nullptr, &descriptorSetLayout[0]));
        }

        /////////////////////////////set 1 layout///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        {
            std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding> setLayoutBindings =
            {

                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutBinding(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 4),

            };

            VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorLayout =
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo(
                    setLayoutBindings.data(),
                    static_cast<uint32_t>(setLayoutBindings.size()));

            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &descriptorLayout, nullptr, &descriptorSetLayout[1]));  
        }

        VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo =
            vks::initializers::pipelineLayoutCreateInfo(
                &descriptorSetLayout[0],
                2);

        VkPushConstantRange pushConstantRange =
            vks::initializers::pushConstantRange(
                VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
                sizeof(pushConstants),
                0);

        // Push constant ranges are part of the pipeline layout
        pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 1;
        pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pPushConstantRanges = &pushConstantRange;

        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pPipelineLayoutCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout));
    }

    void setupDescriptorPool()
    {

        std::vector<VkDescriptorPoolSize> poolSizes =
        {
            vks::initializers::descriptorPoolSize(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1),
            vks::initializers::descriptorPoolSize(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 1),
            vks::initializers::descriptorPoolSize(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1),
            vks::initializers::descriptorPoolSize(VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 1)
        };

        VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo descriptorPoolInfo =
            vks::initializers::descriptorPoolCreateInfo(
                static_cast<uint32_t>(poolSizes.size()),
                poolSizes.data(),
                2);

        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &descriptorPoolInfo, nullptr, &descriptorPool));
    }

    void setupDescriptorSet()
    {
        {
            VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo =
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetAllocateInfo(
                    descriptorPool,
                    &descriptorSetLayout[0],
                    1);

            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, &descriptorSet));


            std::vector<VkWriteDescriptorSet> writeDescriptorSets = {   
                vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(descriptorSet, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, &uniformBuffers.viewBuffer.descriptor), 
                vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(descriptorSet, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 1, &uniformBuffers.dynamicBuffer.descriptor),
                vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(descriptorSet, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 2, &uniformBuffers.dynamicBuffer_second.descriptor),
                vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(descriptorSet, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 3, &uniformBuffers.Buffer_second.descriptor),
            };

            vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(writeDescriptorSets.size()), writeDescriptorSets.data(), 0, nullptr);
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        {
            VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo =
                vks::initializers::descriptorSetAllocateInfo(
                    descriptorPool,
                    &descriptorSetLayout[1],
                    1);

            VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, &descriptorSet_alt));
            std::vector<VkWriteDescriptorSet> writeDescriptorSets = {
            vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(descriptorSet_alt, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 4, &uniformBuffers.dynamicBuffer_second.descriptor),


            };

            vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(writeDescriptorSets.size()), writeDescriptorSets.data(), 0, nullptr);
        }
    }


    void draw()
    {
        vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &waitFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);

        uint32_t imageIndex;
        vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain.swapChain, UINT64_MAX, semaphores.presentComplete, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

        if (waitFences[imageIndex] != VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
            vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &waitFences[imageIndex], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
        }
        waitFences[imageIndex] = waitFences[currentFrame];

        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
        submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

        VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { semaphores.presentComplete };
        VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

        submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex];

        VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { semaphores.renderComplete };
        submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        vkResetFences(device, 1, &waitFences[currentFrame]);


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmdBufInfo = vks::initializers::commandBufferBeginInfo();

        VkClearValue clearValues[2];
        clearValues[0].color = defaultClearColor;
        clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo = vks::initializers::renderPassBeginInfo();
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.x = 0;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset.y = 0;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.width = width;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent.height = height;
        renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = 2;
        renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = clearValues;


        // Set target frame buffer

        renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = frameBuffers[imageIndex];

        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBeginCommandBuffer(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], &cmdBufInfo));
        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        for (int cam = 0; cam < CAM_INSTANCES ; cam ++) {

            glm::mat4 test;
            test = glm::scale(test, glm::vec3((cam+1) *2));
            pushConstants = test;


            vkCmdPushConstants(
                drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex],
                pipelineLayout,
                VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
                0,
                sizeof(pushConstants),
                &pushConstants[0][0]);



            VkViewport viewport = vks::initializers::viewport((float)width / 2, (float)height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            viewport.x = cam* 400;
            vkCmdSetViewport(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], 0, 1, &viewport);

            VkRect2D scissor = vks::initializers::rect2D(width, height, 0, 0);
            vkCmdSetScissor(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], 0, 1, &scissor);


            vkCmdBindPipeline(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline);

            VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = { 0 };
            vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], VERTEX_BUFFER_BIND_ID, 1, &vertexBuffer.buffer, offsets);


            //Different set, can update at a different rate then other Dynamic UBOs in the 0th set. 

            //DynamicAlignments are all same size, mat4 in my implementation.
            uint32_t dynamicOffset  = cam * static_cast<uint32_t>(dynamicAlignment);

            int whichsetisthis = 1;
            int numberofdynamicbuffersinthisset = 1;
            vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, whichsetisthis, 1, &descriptorSet_alt, numberofdynamicbuffersinthisset, &dynamicOffset );


            //Since these 2 dynamic ubos are in the same set, must update at the same rate.
            for (uint32_t j = 0; j < OBJECT_INSTANCES; j++)
            {

                uint32_t dynamicOffset = j * static_cast<uint32_t>(dynamicAlignment);
                uint32_t dynamicOffset1 = cam* static_cast<uint32_t>(dynamicAlignment);
                int whichsetisthis = 0;
                uint32_t d[2];
                d[0] = dynamicOffset;
                d[1] = dynamicOffset1;
                int numberofdynamicbuffersinthisset = 2;
                vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, whichsetisthis,1, &descriptorSet, numberofdynamicbuffersinthisset, d);

                vkCmdDraw(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex], 4, 1, 0, 0);
            }



        }
        vkCmdEndRenderPass(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex]);
        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkEndCommandBuffer(drawCmdBuffers[imageIndex]));


        if (vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, waitFences[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
        }

        VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
        presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

        presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain.swapChain };
        presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

        presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

        vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &presentInfo);

        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
    }
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 450

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor; 

layout (set = 0,binding = 0) uniform UboView 
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 model;
} uboView;

layout (set = 0,binding = 1) uniform UboInstance 
{
    mat4 model; 
} uboInstance;

layout (set = 0,binding = 2) uniform UboInstance_second 
{
    mat4 model; 
} uboInstance_second; 

layout (set = 0,binding = 3) uniform UboView_secondary 
{ 
    mat4 model_secondary;
} uboView_secondary; 

layout (set = 1, binding = 4) uniform UboView_third 
{ 
    mat4 model_third;
} uboView_third;

layout(push_constant) uniform PushConsts {
    mat4 camPos;
} pushConsts;


layout (location = 0) out vec3 outColor;

out gl_PerVertex 
{
    vec4 gl_Position;   
};

void main() 
{
    outColor = inColor;
    mat4 modelView = uboView.view * uboInstance.model *uboView.model*uboView_secondary.model_secondary*pushConsts.camPos*uboInstance_second.model*uboView_third.model_third ;
    vec3 worldPos = vec3(modelView * vec4(inPos, 1.0));
    gl_Position = uboView.projection * modelView * vec4(inPos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Camera transforms are really no different from any other uniform state that you want to ship to the GPU per-frame. Unless you want to waste a bunch of push-constants, you're probably going to use a UBO or a read-only SSBO.

The typical solution is to have some memory set aside for these kinds of things, then allocate a slice from that memory for the current frame you're working on. You then use either a dynamic descriptor to select where an individual draw call's data is, or you provide a descriptor containing an array of data and a push constant providing that object's array index. For your case, where a lot of draws are going to be getting the same data, I'd suggest using a dynamic descriptor.

The main thing is to make sure that you're not overwriting data that is currently being used by the previous frame. So the memory storage needs to be at least double-buffered, and you need appropriate synchronization to ensure that this all works out. Your wait on a fence is probably adequate for this purpose.

How you transfer data to the memory is up to you. If you can use host-writable memory for UBOs, then you can just write to a mapped pointer as you're building your command buffer. If not, then you're going to need some transfer commands. And you can't do that in the middle of a render pass. So you'll need to be building two command buffers simultaneously (one to transfer data, the other to render stuff). You then submit the two command buffers in the proper order.

And of course, you'll need appropriate synchronization regardless of how you write the data to the memory. The synchronization goes before the render pass instance or as a source external subpass dependency.

Comment: Thank you Nicol, I'll use your suggestions and edit my code above once I find the solution.

Comment: @Tom: Questions are supposed to be questions; they don't include the answer. If you want to post an answer, you use the "Add Answer" button.